# Custom Projection Operator using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, entity-framework-6

We have created custom repository class to retrieve objects form entity framework context. Get method always returns whole object.

I wish to include project operator Select as parameter. So that we could pass from outside what needs to be selected & SQL query will be more efficient. Is it doable?

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal DbContext context;        
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just return IQueryable and give user of your repository full power of LINQ? Also, don't use repositories. Especially the "Generic" ones.

Comment: @Euphoric If you are going to tell people not to use repositories, then please give a reason why.

Comment: Have you looked at Automapper projections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties` parameter(property selectors) to the method that does the querying, where `T` is the type of your Entity. Next call following method to get information about each property

```
private static PropertyInfo ResolveProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> property) where T : class
    {
        MemberExpression member;

        UnaryExpression body = property.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (body != null)
        {
            member = (MemberExpression)body.Operand;
        }
        else
        {
            member = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
        }

        PropertyInfo info = (PropertyInfo)(member).Member;
        return info;
    }
```

Now, when you have information about properties, you may continue with custom implementation or make use of `System.Linq.Dynamic`

https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. But doing reflection on one of the core classes of applications doesn't seem to be best option.

Comment: Shouldn't I return IQueryable as suggested by Euphoric

Comment: There's a lot of reflection involved when you work with Entity Framework: Query Compilation, Object Materialization etc, so I don't think that should be a concern you need to worry about much. Yes, `IQueryable` is definitely the way to go since it represents the query declaration (expression) rather then actual result.